# Knowing when a key becomes compromised

Tags: ssh, security, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to determine best practices for identifying a compromised key. I have had very little luck finding any material on this however was hoping there was some kind of service which would notify when a key has been found on the web.

For instance, I have an RSA key. It is posted online somewhere, somehow, but I do not know this and continue to use the key. I'd like to be notified asap that something has been spotted so that the public key can be removed from known areas.

What's the best thing to do?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well if the system containing the private key is ever accessed unauthorised then you should treat the key as such too.

There's no way you can 'share' the private key, and you can't go from public -> private anyway so what you're asking is 'impossible' (within the constraints of PKI). Simply by trying to search for the private key (or some subset of it) you'd be revealing information about the key that you should not share.

I guess a service which attempts to find private keys, compute all the public keys and index them 'could' exist but would be computationally unfeasible, or one which simply provides a non-interactive list of private keys found on the web but this would be unrealistic to implement I think.

Comment: I am not suggesting the public key would be converted to a private key, and not knowing when a private key has been compromised is not always feasible.

As for computationally unfeasible indexing of keys, I disagree. It's not that expensive to compare the keys fingerprints.

Answer (score -1):

You should always generate a random key-pair, and you should always keep the private-key private. It is impossible for an adversary to find the private-key by only knowing what the public-key is. So no-one on the internet should be able to find your private-key.